# Oracle Getting last N records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables (`employees`, `locations`, `access_history`) and I'm trying to get the last N (this case 2) records for each `employee_id`.

The last 2 records are based on the access_history.access.date column. My query below is producing the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "A"."ACCESS_DATE": invalid identifier
```

Can someone please take a look and tell me how to fix this issue. In addition, please let me know if there is a more efficient way to go about solving this problem.

I set up a very simple test case to easily reproduce the problem. Thanks in advance to all who respond.

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Create table employees(
 employee_id NUMBER(6), 
 first_name VARCHAR2(20),
 last_name VARCHAR2(20),
 card_num VARCHAR2(10)
);


INSERT into employees(
 employee_id, 
first_name,
last_name,
card_num)
VALUES
(1, 'Jane', 'Smith', 'A12345');

INSERT into employees(
 employee_id, 
 first_name,
 last_name,
 card_num)
VALUES
(2, 'John', 'Doe', 'N546830');
       
 ALTER TABLE employees
         ADD ( CONSTRAINT employees_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));

CREATE TABLE locations AS
    SELECT level AS location_id,
  'Door ' || level AS location_name,

    CASE           round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'T' 
 END AS location_type
FROM   dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 50;


     ALTER TABLE locations 
         ADD ( CONSTRAINT locations_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (location_id));


create table access_history(
      seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
       employee_id NUMBER(6), 
       card_num varchar2(10),
       location_id number(4),
       access_date date,
       processed NUMBER(1) default 0
    );


INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
VALUES
(1, '1A2B3C', 14,
to_date('20210714 18:35:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'));

INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
VALUES
 (1, '1A2B3C', 15,
to_date('20210715 18:35:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'));

INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
VALUES
 (1, '1A2B3C', 16,
 to_date('20210716 18:35:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'));

 INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
VALUES
(2, 'X1234Y', 16,
to_date('20210716 18:35:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'));

INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
  VALUES
 (2, 'X1234Y', 16,
 to_date('20210715 08:25:10','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'));

 INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
VALUES
 (2, 'X1234Y', 14,
 to_date('20210714 23:36:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

```sql
with rws as (
  select e.employee_id, 
             e.first_name,
             e.last_name,
             e.card_num,
             l.location_id,
             l.location_name,
             a.access_date,
            row_number () over 
 (
      partition by e.employee_id
       order by e.employee_id
  ) rn   
 FROM employees e,
           locations l,
            access_history a
)
 select * from rws
 where  rn <= 2
 order  by employee_id,
 access_date desc;
```

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   CARD_NUM    LOCATION_ID LOCATION_NAME   ACCESS_DATE RN
1   Jane    Smith   A12345  1   Door 1  07152021 18:35:00   2
1   Jane    Smith   A12345  1   Door 1  07142021 18:35:00   1
2   John    Doe N546830 1   Door 1  07152021 18:35:00   2
2   John    Doe N546830 1   Door 1  07142021 18:35:00   1
```

Comment: There's no `a.access_date`, only `rws.access_date`. Same goes for e.employee_id.

Comment: Thanks,  I supplied a screenshot of the output above and based on my data I'm not getting the correct location_id and the dates should be 20210716... and 20210715... can you please let me know what's wrong. Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: Also posted on OTN: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4486915/oracle-getting-latest-n-rows-from-a-group#latest

Answer (score 1):

> My query below is producing the following error:
>
> ```
> ORA-00904: "A"."ACCESS_DATE": invalid identifier
> ```

No, it doesn't; you do not get that error.

> I'm trying to get the last N

Then you need to `ORDER BY` a column that will get you the values; it is unclear from the question what the "last N" should be measured against but assuming it is the access date then you want to `ORDER BY` that in the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

You also need to not `CROSS JOIN` the tables and use an `INNER JOIN`; it is easier to work out what is wrong if you use the ANSI join syntax (rather than the legacy comma join syntax).

For example, you wrote your query as (after changing the `ORDER BY`):

```sql
select *
from   (
  select e.employee_id, 
         e.first_name,
         e.last_name,
         e.card_num,
         l.location_id,
         l.location_name,
         a.access_date,
         row_number () over (
           partition by e.employee_id
           order by a.access_date DESC
         ) rn   
  FROM   employees e
         CROSS JOIN access_history a
         CROSS JOIN locations l
)
where  rn <= 2
order  by employee_id,
access_date desc;
```

Then the output is:

> | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | CARD_NUM | LOCATION_ID | LOCATION_NAME | ACCESS_DATE | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Jane | Smith | A12345 | 1 | Door 1 | 2021-07-16 18:35:00 | 1 |
> | 1 | Jane | Smith | A12345 | 50 | Door 50 | 2021-07-16 18:35:00 | 2 |
> | 2 | John | Doe | N546830 | 1 | Door 1 | 2021-07-16 18:35:00 | 1 |
> | 2 | John | Doe | N546830 | 50 | Door 50 | 2021-07-16 18:35:00 | 2 |

What you want is:

```sql
select *
from   (
  select e.employee_id, 
         e.first_name,
         e.last_name,
         e.card_num,
         l.location_id,
         l.location_name,
         a.access_date,
         row_number () over (
           partition by e.employee_id
           order by a.access_date DESC
         ) rn   
  FROM   employees e
         INNER JOIN access_history a
         ON (e.employee_id = a.employee_id)
         INNER JOIN locations l
         ON (l.location_id = a.location_id)
)
where  rn <= 2
order  by employee_id,
access_date desc;
```

Which outputs:

> | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | CARD_NUM | LOCATION_ID | LOCATION_NAME | ACCESS_DATE | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Jane | Smith | A12345 | 16 | Door 16 | 2021-07-16 18:35:00 | 1 |
> | 1 | Jane | Smith | A12345 | 15 | Door 15 | 2021-07-15 18:35:00 | 2 |
> | 2 | John | Doe | N546830 | 16 | Door 16 | 2021-07-16 18:35:00 | 1 |
> | 2 | John | Doe | N546830 | 16 | Door 16 | 2021-07-15 08:25:10 | 2 |

Comment: Ed, thanks for your expertise and help. Everything works great.